# I need to remove the script Tapestry adds to the bottom of every page

Tags: tapestry

Yes, I know it is important and Tapestry needs it for its JS support and what not, but I do not use Tapestry JS functionality at all.

I have already managed to remove all the generic CSS and JS that is added by Tapestry, but I cannot find a way to remove this script from the bottom of most pages:

```
Tapestry.onDOMLoaded(function() {
    //blebleble
});
```

What I tried is to override the JavaScriptSupport class, providing my own, completely empty implementation. But the script is STILL there! I believe the methods responsible for inserting this script are called `addScript()` but providing empty implementation for them does not solve the problem.

Part of AppModule:

```
@Contribute(ServiceOverride.class)
public static void setupApplicationServiceOverrides(
        MappedConfiguration<Class, Object> configuration, ObjectLocator locator)
{
    configuration.add(JavaScriptSupport.class, new JavaScriptSupportOverride());
}
```

Part of JavaScriptSupportOverride:

```
@Override
public void addScript(String format, Object... arguments)
{
}

@Override
public void addScript(InitializationPriority priority, String format,
        Object... arguments)
{
}
```

I need it quite badly and I would be happy to set bounty when SO permits me.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a strange thing to be doing as you'll break everything. But you could do it by removing the "JavaScriptSupport" [MarkupRendererFilter](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/MarkupRendererFilter.html) from the MarkupRenderer pipeline:

YourAppModule.java

```
public static void contributeMarkupRenderer(OrderedConfiguration<MarkupRendererFilter> config) {
    config.add("JavaScriptSupport", null);
}
```

Tapestry uses MarkupRendererFilters to add things like CSS and JS files to the HTML. Download the tapestry sources and take a look at TapestryModule.java. It seems like you might want to remove / tweak some of the core filters which include:

```
configuration.add("DocumentLinker", documentLinker);
configuration.add("JavaScriptSupport", javaScriptSupport);
configuration.add("RenderSupport", renderSupport);
configuration.add("InjectDefaultStylesheet", injectDefaultStylesheet);
configuration.add("ClientBehaviorSupport", clientBehaviorSupport);
configuration.add("Heartbeat", heartbeat);
configuration.add("ValidationDecorator", defaultValidationDecorator);
```

*** edit ***

References to `after:*` have been changed to `before:*` (since the first filter also runs last).

Another solution is to let all of the core filters run and contribute your own MarkupRendererFilter which is ordered "before:*". This filter could go through the [DOM](http://tapestry.apache.org/dom.html) and remove anything you don't want before it's written to the Response output stream.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. You are right, passing null for JavaScriptSupport was not a great idea :). How would I go about contributing MarkupRendererFilter then? How to order it so that it runs after all other filters?

Comment: Your example removes JavaScriptSupport by passing null. How would I go about adding my own filter that removes JS from DOM? `config.add("something", myfilter.class)`?

Comment: either ```config.add("myfilter", new MyFilter(), "after:*")``` or ```config.addInstance("myfilter", MyFilter.class, "after:*")```. More details [here](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry-ioc-configuration.html) and [here](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ioc/OrderedConfiguration.html)

Comment: Thanks, I have been able to contribute MarkupRenderer filter that runs after all the other filters. Having `MarkupWriter` I do `markupWriter.getDocument()` but I get `null`...

Comment: You'll need to call MarkupRenderer.renderMarkup(writer) before your logic.

Comment: Yay, that worked. We are getting closer but... The `writer.getDocument()` contains everything _except_ this particular script at the end. Even though I use "after:*" constrain. So the script has to be added sometime after the markup renderer filter.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps you need to order your filter ```before:*``` instead of ```after:*```. I know it's counterintuitive but Filters have two interception points (both before and after the main logic). So the first filter will have a chance to execute first AND last.

Comment: That did it. Problem solved. You will receive your bounty tomorrow. Have a great day! :)